# Date format of python / django pdf file

Tags: python, django, date, pdf

I am using python 2.7 & django 1.8.

I am a noob, so the answer to this issue may be obvious, but I have searched SO & Google, and I cannot find an answer.

I have been given some code that creates a pdf. At the footer of the pdf, the created date should be in the format of **May 29, 2016**. The month should be the locale’s abbreviated name ie: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc.

However the date in the pdf is may 29, 2016. The month is lower case and should be proper case.

Here is the relevant code.

base.py setting file code:

```
FORMAL_DATE_FORMAT_PYTHON = 'b d, Y'  # Dec 25, 2016
```

pdf_create_view.py code:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ....
    date_created = date(datetime.datetime.now(timezone), settings.FORMAL_DATE_FORMAT_PYTHON)
```

Output format:

```
Created: may 29, 2016
```

I have tried several things, but I am stumped. Any suggestions to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you create the pdf? `wkhtmltopdf` or some other tool? Pls post the relevant code/template!

Comment: Where is that `date` function coming from?

Comment: Yes `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: @user3354539 then you should post the html template that is used.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what your `date` function does that is being referred to. But you can use:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def form_valid(self, form):
    ....
    date_created = timezone.now()  # This will create a timezone aware datetime
```

Then in the template you can pass in the context:

```
{
    'date_created': timezone.local_time(date_created, timezone.get_current_timezone()).strftime('%b %d, %Y')
    ...
}
```

OR pass the `date_created` in the context and in the template use:

```
{{ date_created|date:"b d Y" }}
```

Documentation on the `date` templatetag can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#date

If the `date` function is the template tag function built into DJango I would use [`pdb`](https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/) and ensure what value is being passed to the template for `date_created`.

If the string is uppercase as it is sent to the template it could be some CSS lowering the first letter or the PDF generator. Try creating a temporary view and see what would be displayed as a HTML file. If it is uppercase then it is something in the PDF generator if not check for CSS lowering or JS.

If the value is lowercase when it is being sent to the template (in your context) you can use `capitalize` to uppercase the first letter.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ....
    date_created = date(datetime.datetime.now(timezone), settings.FORMAL_DATE_FORMAT_PYTHON).capitalize()
```